# Large scripts in IE 11 on Windows 7 PCs only work with Script Debugging Enabled

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer, javascript

I am having an issue with IE 11 on Windows 7 that has been brutally hard to pinpoint. This has been occurring for roughly a month. We have a few websites that when certain large scripts are loading (some, such as jQuery, are fine), the sites take a very long time to load. When IE is clicked during the load, it will give the "long running script" error. There are several things that will allow it to work without the severe load time, which are:

- Enabling "Script Debugging (Internet Explorer)" within the Tools>Advanced menu in IE, our current workaround
- Using Chrome, Firefox, or Edge (for all but one of the sites as it is from a vendor and isn't compatible)
- Using IE 11 on a Windows 10 machine (we are still deployment testing for this OS)
- Using IE on a server, such as the local web server
- Booting the PC into safe mode

I have tried disabling our security software, verified all settings were the same between the Windows 7 and Windows 10 test PCs, rolling back IE updates, using 32 and 64 bit versions, and too many other troubleshooting steps to remember them all. Fiddler was unhelpful and did not show any anomalies during the huge pause. Also, when script debugging is enabled, the supposedly problematic scripts do not throw any errors and just starts working like nothing happened.

My questions would be does anyone know of any GPOs, IE settings that are specific to IE 11 in Windows 7, or voodoo curses that would alter the way that JavaScript is interpreted by IE? Is there something that script debugging would disable that I should know about? Has anyone encountered anything similar after recent IE updates on Windows 7? Using a different browser is unfortunately not an option with one of the sites and Windows 10 deployment is still a ways off for my enterprise.  I am using IE version 11.0.9600.18816CO, update version 11.0.47.

**Edit**

I have also tried running the browser with no addons, with the sites in the sites list for the Intranet zone, and in the Trusted Sites list with no luck.

Comment: I would try the following two things: Firstly disable any add-ons running in IE, and second add the site to the 'Allowed Sites' zone in IE. This will temporally bypass any security settings for IE. See if you get any improvements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Had already tried those, although I tried both of them at once just to ensure it wasn't a combination of things. Same behavior occurred. Added an edit to reflect that.

Comment: Was that the Trusted Sites zone and not the intranet zone?

Comment: Sorry, was Intranet when I attempted initially. I tried Trusted Sites separately, no change.